# T-SQL CONVERT error but TRY_CONVERT no nulls

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In SQL Server 2014 select clause,

```
AVG(CONVERT(DECIMAL(11, 8), p.[Total])) AS [Value]
```

where `p.[Total]` is of type `varchar(50)`, raises this error:

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 8, Line 2
>   Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric

but

```
AVG(TRY_CONVERT(DECIMAL(11, 8), p.[Total])) AS [Value]
```

does **not** return any null values, which it is supposed to do when CONVERT fails. The number of rows returned is the same when I leave out the [Value] column as when I use TRY_CONVERT.

Also, leaving in [Value] with TRY_CONVERT and filtering for nulls with

```
HAVING AVG(TRY_CONVERT(DECIMAL(11, 8), p.[Total])) IS NULL
```

returns no rows. Why does `TRY_CONVERT` seem to work on all rows (no nulls), but `CONVERT` does not?

Comment: Please provide us with sample data that reproduces the issue.

Comment: `AVG()` is `SUM()` / `COUNT()` with a check to prevent a divide by 0. `SUM` ignores `NULL`s entirely. You should see a "null value is eliminated by aggregate" warning in the message output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expression:

```
AVG(TRY_CONVERT(decimal(11, 8), p.[Total]))
```

Is only going to return `NULL` if *all* values fail to convert.

You want a non-aggregation query of the form:

```
select p.total
from t
where try_convert(decimal(11, 8), p.total) is null;
```